# Python shebang: "Permission Denied" in Git-Bash for Windows

Tags: python, windows, git-bash, shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('Test')
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: Permission denied
```

I'm not sure how to correctly call a shebang so that it works in git-for-windows or if there is a setting I need to change?

Comment: Also running into a similar issue. Since the [Open Cataylist Project](https://github.com/Open-Catalyst-Project/ocp) repo I'm using (mine is a mirrored version of this) has precommit hooks that call python, having trouble with using it in Windows.